# JavaFX 2 - Tableview Checkbox not showing value

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx, properties, tableview

I finally managed to track whenever a click happens on a checkbox in my GUI. But now it won't load the correct value of the CheckBox into the gui. Can anyone see what might be wrong? :)

```
roadtrainCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Spot,Boolean>,ObservableValue<Boolean>>()
            {
                public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(CellDataFeatures<Spot, Boolean> param) {
                    return param.getValue().getRoadtrain();
                }   
            });
    roadtrainCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
        CheckBoxTableCell<Spot, Boolean> cell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>(index -> {
            BooleanProperty active = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
            active.addListener((obs, wasActive, isNowActive) -> {
                System.out.println("del");
                rettedeSpots(tableViewId.getItems().get(index).getId());
            });
            return active ;
        });
        return cell ;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating **new** `BooleanProperty`s. Those properties will always be initialized with `false`.

The `cellFactory` is not the place to add listeners. Add listeners to the items instead.

```
roadtrainCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Spot, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(CellDataFeatures<Spot, Boolean> param) {
                return param.getValue().getRoadtrain();
            }
        });

roadtrainCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(roadtrainCol));

ChangeListener<Boolean> roadTrainChangeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    Spot spot = (Spot) ((ReadOnlyProperty) observable).getBean();
    System.out.println("del");
    rettedeSpots(spot.getId());
};

// add/remove listeners when Spots are added to/removed from the list
tableViewId.getItems().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Spot> c) -> {
    while (c.next()) {
        for (Spot s : c.getRemoved()) {
            s.getRoadtrain().removeListener(roadTrainChangeListener);
        }
        for (Spot s : c.getAddedSubList()) {
            s.getRoadtrain().addListener(roadTrainChangeListener);
        }
    }
});

// add listeners to items already in the list
for (Spot s : tableViewId.getItems()) {
    s.getRoadtrain().addListener(roadTrainChangeListener);
}
```

Note that this only works, if you assigned the `Spot` instance containing the `SimpleBooleanProperty` as `bean`, e.g.

```
Spot() {
     this.roadtrain = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "roadtrain");
}
```

or

```
Spot(boolean roadtrain) {
     this.roadtrain = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "roadtrain", roadtrain);
}
```

I just used the `bean` to avoid having tho create new listeners for every item.

Also consider following the naming conventions for JavaFX properties:

- Property getter is named `<propertyName>Property` (not `get<capitalFirstLetterPropertyName>`)
- the getter for the property's value is named `get<capitalFirstLetterPropertyName>`
- the setter for the property's value is named `set<capitalFirstLetterPropertyName>`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'll try get my hands on it asap and hopefully I can get it to work.